# Can Grid Dip Oscillator (GDO) detect WiFi, Bluetooth and NFC?

Tags: ham-radio

Can I use [GDO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_dip_oscillator) to detect those waves? Can I buy one somewhere or I need to build one? I would to have digital one, that will just show the frequency of the waves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a grid-dip oscillator is fundamentally a signal generator, not a signal detector. It is used to measure the characteristics of passive circuits such as RF tanks and and antennas, by measuring how they absorb energy at various frequencies.

What you're looking for would be a [frequency counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_counter) that has an antenna connected to its input. The display will show the frequency of the strongest signal that the antenna is picking up.

Comment: Or preferably (especially with spread spectrum standards) a spectrum analyzer, though the price gets up there. Wifi and blueooth have overlapping frequency assignments, so differentiating them may require something such as a spectrum analyzer which can look at the (time averaged) frequency domain character of the signal, or something which can attempt to interpret the signal as one of those standards (ie, a wifi or bluetooth adapter with a scanning/monitoring mode)