# Antenna that can be used for large range of frequences?

Tags: antenna, wave

Is there an antenna or device that can be used for WiFi, NFC, bluetooth, GSM for use with a frequency counter to measure the frequency of the waves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For laboratory use, it is common to use a [Log-periodic antenna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-periodic_antenna), which is well-behaved over a large frequency range.

Anyway, it will be quite tricky to try to feed the antenna directly to a frequency counter and get a result for the signals you want. You will need a [spectrum analyzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_analyzer), and even then some will be quite tricky to identify (most notably the spread spectrum signals).

Comment: Somone mention spectrum analyzer in the anwser to my question here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42480/can-grid-dip-oscillator-detect-wifi-bluetooth-and-nfc I was asking, if I can use Grid Dip Oscillator for that and someone answer, that I will need to use  frequency counter with antenna connected to its input.

Comment: Grid-dip + antenna + counter is OK, since the Grid-dip will generate a strong carrier signal. The telecom signals you want to measure are not a strong continuous carrier: they are wide-band, low power, and emit in bursts.